# Реферальные "хвосты"

Tags: веб-программирование, php

Здравствуйте) Подскажите, что такое Реферальные "хвосты" и как их делать. Гугл, что то не хочет дружить со мной:((

Answer (score 8, accepted):

все очень просто. если просто разместить ссылку на свой сайт на многих сайтах, то потом сложно отслеживать, по ссылкам с каких сайтов пришли люди. Можно конечно и по реферам, но это усложняет и доверять им не стоит.
Поэтому, многие делают ссылки вида "сайт.нет/разныепараметры&refer=musor". То есть, добавляют ещё один параметр, в котором прописана строка, котрая явно идентифицируется с сайтом, откудова перешли. Некоторые туда прямо вписывают урл сайта, но думаю, так не нужно делать. Можно туда md5 хеш писать, к примеру.

Все это, что приходит, потом просто учитывается в какой-либо базе или просто в логах.

Смысл это делать есть только в том случае, если Вы к примеру платите за размещение ссылки на Вас.

У многих людей подобные "реферальные ссылки" асоциируются с негативом (к примеру - сетевые пирамиды).

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="utm_source" value="<?php echo $_GET['utm_source']; ?>  вот это и есть реферальные хвосты?